# What does a semicolon denote in the context of probability and statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, notation, statistical-inference

I sometimes see the notation $;$ being used in a statistical context

For example, let $f_X(x)$ be the probability density function associated with random variable $X$, then sometimes I see things like $f_X(x| y; \theta)$, where $\theta$ is a set of the mean and the covariance associated with the distribution.

What does these $;$ mean? Any reference helps.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation?  Can you provide a link or reference to the place where it has been written?  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30825/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-semicolon-in-fx-theta) says that it divides data from parameters.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Mainly online notes, I think they are extremely prevalent. For example http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes8.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's used as a grand kind of comma.  In this case, I think $x$ and $y$ refer to possible values of random variables, and $\theta$ an unknown non-random parameter, and the conditional density of $x$ given $y$ might be denoted $f(x|y)$, but the author wants to emphasize the fact that the whole expression  depends on $\theta$ as well, and so might have written $f(x|y,\theta).$ But because in his world $y$ and $\theta$ are different kinds of things, writes $f(x|y;\theta)$ instead.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: No.  I'm away from my library just now, but am sure if I flipped through enough maths stats books, I'd see it, as I have seen it in the past.  Maybe without an explicit discussion of the notation, but in a context where the meaning is clear.  If I find an example, I'll post it.

Comment: @XanderHenderson My copy of *Theoretical Statistics* (1974 edition) by Cox and Hinkley, p.401, eqn (59) has an instance of this notation.  It says: "Now the posterior density of $\Psi_n$ for fixed $\lambda,\zeta$ and data $y$ involves the data only through $y_n$ and is $f_{\Psi_n|Y}(\psi_n|y;\lambda,\zeta)$..."

Comment: I think a more accurate discussion of this notation can be found here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/meaning-of-probability-notations-pzd-w-and-pzd-w

Comment: @aaronsnoswell I would be grateful if you would point out an actual inaccuracy in my answer.  I know statisticians often like use  elaborate typographic methods to distinguish the meaning of the various arguments of functions.  Is it _wrong_ to call these "fancy commas"?  As opposed to merely  disrespectful of your tribe's customs?

Comment: Hi @kimchilover, My understanding is that the semicolon actually carries mathematical meaning, rather than just being a stylistic preference. The discussion I linked highlights that the semicolon indicates the objects to the right of the ';' are parameters, i.e. fixed inputs to the distribution, while the use of a bar indicates the objects to the right of '|' are random variables. So calling them fancy commas actually confuses the meaning. Also, it's not my tribe, I'm just a confused engineer trying to understand some notation I came across :)