# English pronunciation of semi colon in probabilities

Tags: probability, pronunciation

In English, I believe the notation $p(x, z \mid \theta)$ is pronounced something like;

> pee-of-ex-zee-**given**-theta

But I sometimes see a semicolon used, as in $p(x, z \,; \theta)$, which I believe indicates that $\theta$ is a considered as a parameter of the model $p$, not a random variable.

Mathematical interpretation aside, how is the semicolon `;` in this expression pronounced?

Comment: I'm not sure (not English native), but I would pronounce it "pee-of-ex-and-zee- with a parameter theta"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is community-wide consensus on the question of pronunciation, but you are right, the semi-colon is usually meant to indicate that the expression depends on $\theta$, a fixed (non-random) parameter. I would personally pronounce it as "given-theta" or "given-fixed-theta".

You could also write $p_{\theta}(x, z)$, which would be pronounced "pee-sub-theta-of-ex-zee".

References on the meaning of the semi-colon:
[What does a semicolon denote in the context of probability and statistics?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10234/meaning-of-probability-notations-pzd-w-and-pzd-w) and
[Meaning of probability notations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2559085/what-does-a-semicolon-denote-in-the-context-of-probability-and-statistics)

Comment: I personally much prefer the subscript notation :) Thanks for the input!